# Convert Perametertype into class not working

Tags: java, javafx

I am Working on JavaFx.i want to display Number Of Node that is used in javaFX class.for that i get class and its start method.

`NodeClassTree` is a javaFX Class which i created with only start method and

in following code i get the start method. and i get method's perameters as a Class.

but i cant cast that class in to `Stage` Class object.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Method myClasss = NodeClassTree.class.getDeclaredMethod("start",Stage.class);

            System.out.println(myClasss.getParameterTypes()[0].getCanonicalName());

            Class<?> stg = myClasss.getParameterTypes()[0];

            System.out.println(stg);

            stg.cast(new Stage()); //.........[1] Not Working

            //stg.cast(new Object()); //.........[2] Not Working
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR : "+e);
        }
    }
```

NodeClassTree.java

```
    public class NodeClassTree extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage){
            BorderPane bdrpn = new BorderPane();
        Scene cin = new Scene(bdrpn);
primaryStage.setScene(cin);

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.stage.Window.<init>(Window.java:1191)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:239)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:227)
    at application.Controls.GetTree.main(GetTree.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:285)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:667)
    at javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:79)
    ... 4 more
```

i get name of class using `getCanonicalName()` but i want to convert `geterameterTypes()[0]` into the Stage class  after that i want to get `Scene` object

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please include the stack trace or the compiler error.

Comment: i just update my Question,, its give me runtime Error

Comment: You have two static main methods. Not sure what you are doing here.

Comment: i want to get Stage object from `start` Method in javafx class. for that i can get `scene` and another object releted to `scene` object

Comment: @Bhola You cannot get a `Stage` object from there, because `start()` is only called if your application is started from `NodeClassTree::main()`. So, if you started your application from the other `main()`, then `NodeClassTree::start()` will be nothing except a method signature.

Comment: is there any way to get that `stage` object or get that `scene` object included in start method.

Comment: If `application.Controls.GetTree` class is supposed to be capable of counting the number of nodes in the primary stage of *any* `Application` class, then no. Otherwise, you can let `application.Controls.GetTree` extend from `NodeClassTree` class, override `start()` method where you call `super.start()`, then use the reference of `primaryStage` to do what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176109/discussion-between-bhola-and-jai).

Comment: i have many Fx classes , i can extends only one class...!

Comment: What do you mean by "_Number Of Node that is used in javaFX class_"? Do you mean you want the total number of `Node`s currently in the scene graph of a particular `Stage`? Also, your last sentence seems to indicate a misunderstanding about what reflection is capable of and what it is used for.

Comment: yes you see rigtht..! i want total number of node

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, you are doing a UI update on a non-UI thread. You should use [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: Has the JavaFX platform been started? You have a `launch` in the `NodeClassTree`, but if you don't start your app there but in the other `main` the JavaFX platform is not started, and thus no GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, so it may not work. In fact, I would say this is likely *not* to work, but you *can try*.

```
public class GetTree extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Application appToTest = new NodeClassTree();
        appToTest.start(primaryStage);

        Scene scene = primaryStage.getScene();
        // And so on...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```